# How to use uniq Unix command and specify input and output file?

Tags: uniq

I'm confused on the use of the `uniq` command. Can anyone **explain this command** and how to use it?

How can I use `uniq` without specifying any option? Any example would be helped and appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading the man page for uniq? `man uniq`.

Answer (score 1):

uniq read file line-by-line, and only consider a duplicate when the current line is exactly the same as the last line,

i.e for a input file like this,

```
1
1
2
1
```

You'll get an output like this,

```
1
2
1
```

To use it, you can either run it though a pipe, i.e

`command | uniq`

Or get the input from a file like this,

`uniq < input > output`

Comment: I have to downvote this because it doesn't appear to answer the question at all. The question is about `uniq`, not `sort`. Data does need to be sorted for `uniq` to work, but that is not included here.

Comment: @jordanm ah, I take it wrong, answer updated, thanks for pointing out

Comment: However, all my uses of `uniq` combine with `sort`

Comment: Downvote removed

Comment: For completeness, I'd suggest including a demonstration of how `uniq` and `sort` work together; I agree that `uniq` is most useful when combined with `sort`.